# Apache Camel - Read Json from Rest and then convert to Java Object

Tags: java, json, rest, apache-camel

Currently, my application can

1. Read a json file from local file system
2. Convert to Java Object using ObjectMapper of Jackson Library

Now, I want to change the process to

1. Read a json content from rest endpoint
2. Log the json content
3. Convert to Java Object using ObjectMapper of Jackson Library

However, I encounter a strange problem that the body in exchange disappear after display. Would like to know what possible setting am I missing?

**The XML content**

```
<camelContext id="admin_sysHttpRec_ctx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="false">

    <restConfiguration component="restlet" host="localhost" port="9394"></restConfiguration>

    <rest path="/sys">
        <put uri="/json" id="admin_sysHttpJson_receiver">
            <to uri="direct:sysJson.process"/>
        </put>
    </rest>

    <route id="admin_sysHttpJson_route">
        <from uri="direct:sysJson.process"/>
        <log message="sysHttpJsonManage BODY: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
        <process ref="sysJsonManage"/>
        <transform>
            <constant>Success!</constant>
        </transform>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

**The Processor**

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("body: " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));

    // Setup jsonFileContext
    //      byte[] body = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
    String bodyStr = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    byte[] body = bodyStr.getBytes();
    LOG.info("body.length: " + body.length);
    LOG.info("(String) body.length: " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).length());

    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFileContext jsonFileContext = objectMapper.readValue(body, JsonFileContext.class);
        exchange.setProperty("jsonFileContext", jsonFileContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exchange.setException(e);
    }
}
```

**Raw payload in http request**

```
{
    "direction":"OUT",
    "srcEncoding":"",
    "destEncoding":""
}
```

**The result**

```
20160929 15:53:33.193 [Restlet-4844614] INFO admin_sysHttpJson_route - sysHttpJsonManage BODY: {
    "direction":"OUT",
    "srcEncoding":"",
    "destEncoding":""
}
20160929 15:53:33.193 [Restlet-4844614] INFO com.test.admin.sys.http.SysJsonManage - body: 
20160929 15:53:33.194 [Restlet-4844614] INFO com.test.admin.sys.http.SysJsonManage - body.length: 0
20160929 15:53:33.194 [Restlet-4844614] INFO com.test.admin.sys.http.SysJsonManage - (String) body.length: 0
20160929 15:53:33.355 [Restlet-4844614] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-XXXXX-61466-1475135595982-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-XXXXX-61466-1475135595982-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@67e6a2; line: 1, column: 1]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[admin_sysHttpJson_] [admin_sysHttpJson_] [http://localhost:9394/sys/json?restletMethods=PUT                             ] [       181]
[admin_sysHttpJson_] [restBinding1      ] [                                                                              ] [         4]
[admin_sysHttpJson_] [admin_sysHttpJson_] [direct:sysJson.process                                                        ] [       162]
[admin_sysHttpJson_] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[admin_sysHttpJson_] [process1          ] [ref:sysJsonManage                                                             ] [       160]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@67e6a2; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3721)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2819)
    at com.test.admin.sys.http.SysJsonManage.process(SysJsonManage.java:31)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletConsumer$1.handle(RestletConsumer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter.handle(MethodBasedRouter.java:54)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper$1.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:64)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Camel version I am using is 2.17.0

Comment: you can't read InputStream twice because it will close after the first reading. That's why you see "end-of-input". Try to change the logic of your app

Comment: Why don't you in the processor print out the values in  String bodyStr = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);    byte[] body = bodyStr.getBytes(); and see what they contain? Do they really contain the body or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @kostyan_SV and @Cyäegha to point out the problem sources from the InputStream.

Since the problem sources from the InputStream, one simple solution I can think of is to convert the body type from InputStream to String by `convertBodyTo` feature.

```
<route id="admin_sysHttpJson_route">
    <from uri="direct:sysJson.process"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    ...
</route>
```

Noted that it will be better to use bindingMode method suggested by @Cyäegha if not need to do any work related to original payload between rest endpoint and unmarshal step.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: the input message body is a stream (e.g. an `InputStream`), which can only be consumed once. One solution is to enable stream caching, either globally (for all routes in the Camel context) or per-route. For more details, see [the official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html).

XML - global configuration:

```xml
<camelContext streamCache="true">
    ...
</camelContext>
```

XML - single route:

```
<route streamCache="true">
    ...
</route>
```

Java - global configuration:

```java
context.setStreamCache(true);
```

Java - single route:

```java
from("...")
.streamCaching()
.to("...");
```

It's also worth noting that, instead of using a processor to manually deserialize your JSON input, you could use Camel's [JSON DataFormat](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) with the `unmarshall` step in the DSL.

Or even simpler, just configure the REST endpoint to do the binding for you and output a POJO, by configuring the `bindingMode` in the [REST DSL](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html). Something like this should do the trick (I only tested the Java DSL, hopefully the XML syntax is correct):

```xml
<restConfiguration component="restlet" host="localhost" port="9394" bindingMode="json" />

<rest path="/sys">
    <put uri="/json" id="admin_sysHttpJson_receiver" type="JsonFileContext.class">
        <to uri="direct:sysJson.process"/>
    </put>
</rest>
```

In both cases, you will need the `camel-jackson` component on your classpath.

Comment: Just have some tests with StreamCache, it will still be a problem to access multiple times within a bean or processor (can be read by the first access only). Other than using StreamCache, I am thinking if convert Body to String type could fix the issue.

Comment: Sure, that's a possibility (one difference is that stream caching will cache data to the disk if it's larger than a configurable limit, but that only really matters for large messages). But t if you're going to unmarshal the JSON data to a POJO anyway, it seems simpler to do it as early as possible - and then you only have to deal with your Java model.